# Is there a race condition when cancelling the delayed command in this coundown timer?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I have implemented a countdown timer that has a "Reset" button for cancelling a countdown:

```
set LAUNCHTIME 5
set message $LAUNCHTIME
set afterId {}

proc countdown {remainingSeconds} {
    global afterId message
# **
    if {$remainingSeconds > 0} {
        set message $remainingSeconds
# **
        set afterId [after 1000 [list countdown [expr {$remainingSeconds - 1}]]]
    } else {
        set message "Takeoff!"
        .start configure -state normal
    }
}

label .message -textvariable message
button .start -text Start -command {
    .start configure -state disabled
    countdown $LAUNCHTIME
}
button .reset -text Reset -command {
    # Reset timer, message, and button.
    after cancel $afterId  ;# <- XXX: Could this cause a race condition?
    set message $LAUNCHTIME
    .start configure -state normal
}

grid .message
grid .start
grid .reset
grid anchor . center
```

This is what it looks like when the "Start" button is pressed:

[image: GIF of countdown timer]

Is there a possible race condition when the "Reset" button is pressed while a countdown is occurring? I am worried about the possibility that the "Reset" button is pressed while the program is executing the parts between the double asterisks (`**`) in the code above. At that point, there is no delayed command that is scheduled to execute, so the "Reset" does not cancel any delayed command. However, right after, a new delayed command will be scheduled to execute (`set afterId [after 1000 ...]`), even though the user has intended to reset the countdown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tcl runs single threaded (at least within a single interpreter). Events are only handled in the event loop. That means that you don't have to worry that something happens that could change things while a sequential block of code is executed.

If the user clicks the Reset button while the `countdown` proc runs, the proc continues all the way to the end. At that point the event loop resumes and handles the button-click by executing the code attached to the -command option of the button. That cancels the after event, so `countdown` will not be called again.

Similarly, if the `after` event expires while the code attached to the Reset button runs, the code completes, canceling the after event before the code of the `after` event starts.